Cutting video based on the spectrogram of its audio
I have a lot of video footage. I want to cut interesting parts into a smaller video. I have found the best way to find interesting parts is looking at the spectrogram of the audio and find regions with interesting patterns in it (eg. the talking part, the music part, silence etc.).
Currently I'm using Audacity, I load the audio of the video in there, scroll through the spectrogram, select the interesting part. But Audacity does not have a feature to copy the selection start and length times to clipboard. So I have to look at the selection toolbar and manually copy the timestamps into a text file, then I use a script that turns that into an ffmpeg command line to cut the video. Needless to say this is time consuming and is very error prone. There must be a better way to do this.
So I'm looking for either a video editor that allows me to load the footage and then switch to spectrogram view to pick the interesting parts. This would be nice because sometimes it would be nice to see the image too to make a better cut. Or an audio editor with spectrogram view that allows me to copy selection timestamps to the clipboard in a format that ffmpeg understands. That would faster and less error prone, than manually copying them.

Openshot can do that within bounds: add your video file to a new project, drag the video to one of the tracks in the "timeline" pane, right click on the track, "Display"->"Waveform". You can then use the "scissors" tool to cut up the track at the positions you want, remove unwanted sections, rearrange the video etc. (read the openshot getting started!). Using openshot rather than ffmpeg's command line might be reducing the error probability, anyways, because it's easier to check what you're doing!
two issues, though:

"waveform" is just loudness view, not a spectrogram
it's slow to compute that view for long videos, for some reason.

Alternative software would be kdenlive, whihc I'm not as familiar with, but in my test is much faster (same principle, same "loudness view").
Blender3D is supposed to have a really nice video editor with the ability to display audio waveforms as well, but I've only used blender for 3D modelling – some 15 years ago, so I can't really comment on this.
On the professional side, Davinci Resolve has a free version, that can do all the things you'd need (they earn money if you buy a control board or a movie studio grade system with lots of addons); it's got a bit more to learn, but it's really polished and nice. But I don't think even that has spectrogram support directly in the video editor.
So, personally, my best guess would be to look at the waveform display in either openshot or kdenlive (depending on whose source code style looks more appealing to me after 5 minutes), and modify it to show the kind of signal I need. But I'm a C++ developer with a focus on high-rate signal processing; this might not be a relevant option to you.
The next best option would be using e.g. ffmpeg to generate a video showing the waveform you want to see for each frame. (I think that's literally a filter in ffmpeg that exists!)
Then, you add that video as second video stream to your video file, open it in kdenlive, set the "Thumbnails" to "All frames" in the audio visualization video track's right-click options, and use the that as cutting helper. In the end, you can just remove that "helper" video track.

Spectrogram is a must for me, because the patterns I'm looking for is best seen in frequency space, loudness doesn't work for that.

well, then see the last three paragraphs of my answer :)
